# PHP database not working

Tags: php, mysql

I made this simple database function and a simple user class, but i can't implement the database connection inside the class.

dbconfig.php

```
<?php
session_start();


$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";

try {
  $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrm', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```

This is the class:

```
 <?php

 class user
{
   private $db;

   function __construct($con){
      include_once '..\dbconfig.php';
      $this->db=$con;
    }

   function listargeral($departamento){
      try{
       $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users where departamento=:departamento");
    $stmt->execute(array(':departamento'=>$departamento));
    while($userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo ' <li data-jstree=\'{ "icon" : "fa fa-user" }\'>';
            echo $userRow['nome']." - ".$userRow['acesso'];
            echo '</li>';
    }
} Catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();}
}
   function logado(){
      if(isset($_SESSION['sessao'])){
         return true;
     }
  }

   function entrar($username, $password){
      try{
            $stmt=$this->db->prepare("SELECT * from users where 
            user_name=:username LIMIT 1");
            $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$username));
            $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if($stmt->rowcount()>0){
                 $_SESSION['sessao']=$userRow['userid'];
                 return true;
          }
     }

     catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
     }
```

There is any alternative?
Thank you guys, i'm still learning.

UPDATE, header page for example:

```
<!doctype html>


<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';
include_once 'Class/class.user.php';
$user= new user($con);


// VERIFICAR SE ESTÁ LOGADO
 if($user -> logado()==""){
   $user->redirect('login.php');

}
```

Comment: Errors? Warnings? Where do you call this class? etc etc.

Comment: Have you install pdo library ?

Comment: Okay, so that code doesn't call `listargeral` I'm getting less and less sure what your question / problem is...

Comment: @JonStirling , i updated the code again, it's giving me:  
Notice: Undefined variable: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm2\header.php on line 9

Fatal error: Call to a member function logado() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\hrm2\header.php on line 9

Comment: Should i change databse function to a class?´

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you are including the `dbconfig.php` file twice, once in your main index page and once in your class. This is not necessary.

The mistake you are making is a scoping mistake. You are assuming that your variable `$con` as set in your `dbconfig.php` file is available outside of that file, which it is not.

There are two ways to make it available with the scope of your class file:

1. `return $con;` <-- add this to the end of your `dbconfig.php` file.
2. Change `$con` into a global variable with two steps:-

   A) declare it as global in `dbconfig.php` like so `global $con;` 
   B) declare it
       again in your class file at the top: `global $con`

Either should work.

**E.g. 1 – Using global scope**

```
<?php
session_start();


$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";

global $con; // mark it as globally scoped

try {
  $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrm', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

```
<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';
include_once 'Class/class.user.php';
global $con; // mark it as globally scoped
$user= new user($con);


// VERIFICAR SE ESTÁ LOGADO
 if($user -> logado()==""){
   $user->redirect('login.php');

}
```

```
class user
{
   private $db;

   function __construct($con){
      // include_once '..\dbconfig.php'; // removed this, redundant
      $this->db=$con;
    }
}
```

**E.g. 2: using return from a file**

```
<!doctype html>


<?php

require_once 'dbconfig.php';
$con = include_once 'Class/class.user.php';

$user= new user($con);


// VERIFICAR SE ESTÁ LOGADO
 if($user -> logado()==""){
   $user->redirect('login.php');

}
```

```
<?php
session_start();


$db_user="root";
$db_pass="";


try {
  $con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hrm', $db_user, $db_pass);
  $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

return $con; // return the variable here
```

```
<?php

class user
{
   private $db;

   function __construct($con){
      // include_once '..\dbconfig.php'; // removed this, redundant
      $this->db=$con;
    }
}
```